# .NET and sql server database link

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm a real noob in .NET and i'm trying to link a simple command line application (in C#) with a SQL server database. I'm now able to connect the program with the database but not to recover the data that are in it. Here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
            string queryString = "SELECT USER_ID FROM dbo.ISALLOCATEDTO;";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = queryString;
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    int i = 0;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        i++;
                        Console.WriteLine("Field "+i);
                        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}",reader[0]);
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            //Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
            string x = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static private string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return "Data Source=FR401388\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;";
                + "Integrated Security=SSPI";
        }
    }
}
```

But when i'm running it and even if my table is not empty (I've seen it in the sql server studio), I cannot recover the data by using the read() method. 
What I've done so far : try to change the name of the datatable with a fake one : the datatable is not found (so the link between sql server database and programm seems to be valid).

I'm using Windows Authentication in sql server, dunno if it's changing anything... (Once again : i'm very new to all of that).

Thanks !

Comment: This code should work, if you really have data in your table. A possible cause is: You are looking at a different database. This is quite common if you use Server Explorer inside VS with a connectionstring different from the one used in code

Comment: Yeah that's it, I change the whole database and now, it's working. Thanks !

Comment: I will change this comment as an answer then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work.
A possible cause is: You are looking at a different database.
This is quite common if you use Server Explorer inside VS with a connectionstring different from the one used in code.

Comment: If you have multiple data sources, check if the data source is correct or not. (I had the same issue and my data source was incorrect)